# How to prevent from blocking the text on the right end in Rstudio panel?

Tags: rstudio

Rstudio main panel always blocks the tail of the text on the right because of dragging bar on the right. Is there anyway to prevent this?

[image]

Comment: Did you try making some adjustments in View > Panes